# Rails AJAX request is returned 5 times instead of one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to do a simple AJAX request using link_to :remote option and display the response dynamically. The problem is that I get 5 responses instead of one. Why this might be happening?

page.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to item.title, item_path(item, :format => :js), :remote => true %>
```

show.js.erb:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'items/show.html.erb') %>").insertAfter('#sortable');
$('#show_item').slideDown();
```

items_controller.rb:

```
def show
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end
```

Update: I'm using jQuery. Gemset includes Devise, paperclip and simple_form. I'm having also similar problem when using :confirm with link_to. The thing is that this confirmation dialog is then displayed 5 times regardless of what you press.

There is only one item with 'sortable' id in the generated html:

```
<ul id="sortable"> 
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><a href="/items/10.js" data-remote="true">Another item</a></li> 
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><a href="/items/9.js" data-remote="true">test</a></li> 
     </ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you get 5 responses?

Comment: Which JS framework do you use ? is it jQuery ? It is not possible to get 5 responses to one request, I guess there were 5 requests also, please check that too.

Comment: Problems like this are often the results of events bubbling up. Ensure that clicking your link stops the bubbling after making the request.

Comment: Do you have more than one object with the ID of 'sortable'?

Comment: There is only one 'sortable' id in the HTML:  <ul id="sortable"> 
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><a href="/items/10.js" data-remote="true">Another item</a></li> 
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><a href="/items/9.js" data-remote="true">test</a></li> 
     </ul>

Comment: How do you prevent bubbling up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this problem with different links, right?

Your link handler has been registered multiple times (you can easily check that by using firebug in firefox or the developer tools in chrome, just click the link and look up how many requests are getting sent up, or console.log the handler)

This can happen if you register remote links dynamically (after an asynchronous page fragment load, for instance) and the easiest fix is then to mark your link as registered (for example, by adding a class 'registered') and not register those again, like this

```
# Link registration
$('a.my_link:not(.registered)').click(function(e) {
  #your code here
}).addClass('registered');
```

If you have not yourself written any click event handlers in jQuery, check for libraries doing that for you. Look for something like:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('a[data-remote="true"]').click(function() {
    #some code here...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! That was pretty much the case. I checked the code and here is the problem causing that behaviour:

application.html.erb

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.4.min', 'rails', 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min', 'rails', 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.prettyPhoto', 'rails', 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack', 'rails', 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'placeholder', 'rails', 'application' %>
```

The thing is that I'm including here 'rails' and 'application' scripts with every other js file. Here is the fix:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.4.min', 'rails', 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.prettyPhoto' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'placeholder' %>
```

Removing those solved multiple AJAX GET requests, as well as :confirm dialogs displaying multiple times.

Also learned how to use Firebug for AJAX debugging :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using the asset pipeline. `assets:precompile` copies the content of all js files into the application.js, when you now open the page in the browser and the `application.js` file gets cached, and start again in developent, the browser will load the `application.js` and the `jquery_ujs.js` file at the same time. So there are 2 remote handlers registered at the same time.

Cleaning the browser cache was the solution for me. (Maby this will help some others running in to similar problems)